# Can I share a mutex between shared_lock and unique_lock in the same thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++17, mutex

Consider the following function:

```cpp
 std::shared_mutex mutex;
 
 void foo() {
     std::shared_lock readLock{ mutex };
     // ...
     // read-only part of the function
     // ...
     {
         std::unique_lock lock{ mutex, std::adopt_lock }
         // ...
         // read/write part
         // ...
     }
     // ... some other read part ...
 }
```

Initially the function had only one, `std::unique_lock` for all its parts. It worked fine, but as part of optimisation it got some sections wrapped with a `std::shared_lock` instead. To me it looked completely legit, but after playing around with it it turned out that some dead-locks started to appear (not necessarily in the function, but it became apparent that this change was the root cause of the problem)

Could anyone please elaborate if such an approach is well defined and why exactly it makes deadlock problems to appear?

Comment: First: This never locks the mutex for writing, only for reading. Second: The destructor.of unique lock will unlock the mutex, but it was not locked before.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to upgrade a shared lock to a unique lock. You're doing it wrong - `std::shared_mutex` is not recursive and not upgradable. Release the shared lock first, then lock exclusively normally.

```cpp
std::shared_mutex mutex;

void foo()
{
    {
        std::shared_lock readLock{ mutex };
        // ...
        // read-only part of the function
        // ...
    }
    {
        std::unique_lock writeLock{ mutex };
        // ...
        // read/write part
        // ...
    }
    // ... some other read part ...
}
```

There was an `std::upgrade_lock` in the proposal [N3568](https://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3568.html) but it didn't make it into the standard.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling unique_lock with adopt_lock, which does not lock the mutex on construction. You might want to release readLock before you lock unique_lock. Alternatively, you could add a separate mutex for the unique_lock section.